# resize/change aspect ratio of PGS subtitles with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

i have some blu-ray rips that i have re-encoded. they were letterboxed and so now have resolutions of 1920x816, 1920x804, etc. and this has caused some issues with the subtitles.

in some video players (notibly VLC), the subtitles appear squished and higher up than they should be, and i rather they werent. i figure this is because the picture based PGS subtitles were encoded for a video with a 1920x1080 (16:9) resolution, not a 1920x816 (2.35:1) resolution, and so applications are resizing them to the resolution of the video, which is resulting in a distorted look.

i noticed there is a -canvas_size option for subtitles in ffmpeg and thought that it may fix my issue, but after using it, it seems to have no effect.
command used:

> ffmpeg -canvas_size 1920x816 -i input.mks -c:s copy out.sup

Comment: Is converting them to text based subtitles an option? [SubtitleEdit](https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit/releases) can read PGS subtitles and use OCR to convert them which neatly sidesteps the "squished" problem by letting the client deal with subtitles properly.

Comment: @Mokubai is there a way to batch convert subtitles using SubtitleEdit or other program? id rather not do it manually as i have quite a few subtitles to convert

Comment: SubtitleEdit does have a "Batch" mode under Tools -> Batch, but I've never used it. I'm not sure how it works with bitmap subtitles as they'd need OCR.

Comment: @Mokubai i will have  look at it. thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 3):

You need to re-encode the subtitles as well to make the `canvas-size` option take effect:

```
ffmpeg -canvas_size 1920x816 -fix_sub_duration -i in.mkv \
    -map 0
    -vf crop=1920:816:0:128,scale=1280:-2 \
    -c:s dvdsub \
    -c:a ac3 \
    -c:v libx264 -preset medium -crf 20 -profile:v main -level 4.1 \
    out.mkv
```

The option `-fix_sub_duration` is necessary with some subtitles codecs, especially DVB subtitles, because the duration in the original packet is only a rough estimate and the end is actually marked by an empty subtitle frame.

This option works by waiting for the next packet in the same stream and adjust the duration of the first to avoid overlap.Failing to use this option when necessary can result in exaggerated durations and muxing failures due to non-monotonic timestamps.

A side effect of this option is that it delays the output of all streams until the next subtitle packet is decoded, potentially increasing memory consumption and latency a lot.

Comment: after some trial and error it seems that `-canvas_size` takes the **original** aspect ratio so in the OP's case it should be `-canvas_size 1920x1080`.

Comment: the subtitles won't disappear problem can be solved with the `-fix_sub_duration` option